# Consolidate the php version server or command line

Tags: apache-http-server, php

In Commandline

`$which php`

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

`$php -v`

```
PHP 7.2.10 (cli) (built: Sep 14 2018 07:07:08) ( NTS )
```

On Apache check  phpinfo();

apache2handler

```
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) PHP/7.1.16
```

I don't understand how apache decides the php path.

How can I make the apache to use the same php as commandline??

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache configuration file. There are a couple of things in it that may be used to point to where PHP resides. The first directive is `PHPIniDir` which may be set to tell Apache where PHP resides.

The other directive is `LoadModule php7_module` which tells Apache where to find the PHP  module Apache should use.